# VBA Excel for Extracting a ## after a _ underscore

Tags: excel, vba, split, underscore.js, extract

I have a dataset of 9 digit numbers followed by an underscore and then followed by two digit year.

For example:

```
123456789_17
123456789_16
...
```

Currently I have a code to delete anything after the digit before the underscore"

```
Sub Trunc3()
  Range("AF1:AF10000") = Evaluate(Replace("IF(ROW(),LEFT(@,FIND("" "",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" & _
                               "@,""_"","" ""),""_"","" "")&"" "")-1))", "@", "E1:E100000"))
End Sub
```

Instead, I would like to separate the output into two columns:
First column should be the 9 digit number:  123456789
Second column should be the two digit year:  17

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use text to columns, it is on the data tab.  Use a custom delimiter of `_`

Comment: Using `Split()` would be a natural VBA approach, if VBA is even needed. What you have now is much too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Using `TextToColumns`:

```
Sub SplitText()
    Range("AF:AF").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AF1"), _
                                 DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                 Other:=True, _
                                 OtherChar:="_", _
                                 FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
End Sub
```

Using `Split()` method:

```
Sub SplitText1()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("AF:AF")

    Dim c As Range, v As Variant
    For Each c In r
        v = Split(c.Value, "_")
        c.Value = v(0)
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = v(1)
    Next c
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

You can loop on each cell and set its value accordingly.

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Range("AG:AG")
    If IsEmpty(r.Offset(0, -1).Value) Then Exit For
    Select Case r.Value
        Case 16:   r.Value = 2016
        Case 17:   r.Value = 2017
        Case Else: r.Value = 2015
    End Select
Next r
```

Comment: Thanks. Using the Text to Columns methodology, how can I add 2016 when the result is 16, and 2017 when the result is 17? Also, if the result is blank due to no underscore, how can I make those results 2015? –

Comment: See edit. Just loop through the cells and update the value accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Check the column name, and run it after the TextToColumns.

Comment: How can i Fix the "Subscript out of range" issue?  Thanks again

Comment: in the loop-  For Each r In Range("Ag:Ag").   If I place a single cell,  (Ex. Range("A14"), it works.  just when I place a range then it doesn't populate

Comment: Sub SplitText()
   Range("e:e").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("af1"), _
                                 DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                 Other:=True, _
                                 OtherChar:="_", _
                                 FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
End Sub
Sub SplitText2()
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Range("Ag:Ag")
    If IsEmpty(r.Offset(0, -1).Value) Then Exit For
    Select Case r.Value
        Case 16:   r.Value = 2016
        Case 17:   r.Value = 2017
        Case Else: r.Value = 2015
    End Select
Next r End Sub

Comment: now it works for me too.  Thanks so much for you time and efforts